# Executar site SILEX em hospedagem compartilhada

Tags: silex

Pessoal desenvolvi um site usando o Silex Micro Framework para um cliente e preciso hospeda-lo na locaweb com uma hospedagem compartilhada. O Silex assim como o Laravel e outros frameworks o index.php não fica no raiz do site e sim na pasta Public. Nesta hospedagem não tenho como mudar a pasta root do site. Como eu faria para fazer o redirecionamento para o index na pasta public?
Obrigado

Comment: Talvez [essa página](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html#apache) da documentação possa ajudar.

Comment: @Qmechanic73 eu fiz conforme a explicação e não deu certo. Veja se fiz corretamente. (http://pastebin.com/JDAGtd2f)

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Bem, se meu comentário ajudar alguém.

Veja, é possível ter uma aplicação com a index em webroot, isso segundo a documentação.
Na documentação também é exemplificado como redirecionar para outro caminho fora do webroot, caso assim queira.
"If your site is not at the webroot level you will have to uncomment the RewriteBase statement and adjust the path to point to your directory, relative from the webroot."
Então para quem ainda tiver dúvidas, pode se informar em: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/web_servers.html

Vou deixar aqui uma configuração que pode ajudar:
Um exemplo para uma app com os arquivos na pasta '\web' e o core do Silex no webroot '\':

```
/public_html/.htaccess:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
     RewriteEngine On 
     RewriteRule ^$ /web/ [L] 
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/ 
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 
     RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d 
     RewriteRule ^website.com/(.*[^/])$ http://www.website.com/$1/ [R=301] 
</IfModule>

/public_html/web: 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     Options -MultiViews 

     RewriteEngine On 
     #RewriteBase / 
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
     RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```